# convert Dockerfile ADD to linux cp

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Reading [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/popestepheng/meteor-production-docker-example/blob/master/Dockerfile) .  line 9:

```
ADD . ./meteorapp
```

I am trying to execute this command on the ubuntu terminal manually thus to understand the effect of each line.

Does it translate to:

```
#cp . /home/meteorapp/meteorapp
```

or

```
#cp . /home/meteorapp
```

since the first does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line is doing:

```
. ./meteorapp
```

which is not equivalent to `cp` current directory (`.`).

Here, `.` (`source`) is a shell builtin, that is used to run commands from file(s) (precisely it's argument(s)) in the current session of shell.

In your case, the file `meteorapp` from current directory (`./`), is being `source`-ed.

Comment: But when line 9 is reached, there is no file `meteorapp` in the current directory `./` as I look at the previous lines being ever created.